# How to open attachment list of media?

Tags: android, messaging, android-contentprovider, attachment

In Android messaging, when click on attach it open the list of content provider like **Camera, Gallery, Audio, Video etc**. How to open the same list on button click?
Like this :
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is actually a little complex: you need to call a method like this in your Activity

```
private void showAddAttachmentDialog() {
         AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
         builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_dialog_attach);
         builder.setTitle(R.string.add_attachment);

         AttachmentTypeSelectorAdapter mAttachmentTypeSelectorAdapter = new AttachmentTypeSelectorAdapter(this, AttachmentTypeSelectorAdapter.MODE_WITH_SLIDESHOW);
         }
         builder.setAdapter(mAttachmentTypeSelectorAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                 addAttachment(mAttachmentTypeSelectorAdapter.buttonToCommand(which), replace);
                 dialog.dismiss();
             }
         });

         builder.show();
     }
```

to show the dialog, and then this is the actual implementation of the selection adapter.

```
package com.android.mms.ui;

import com.android.mms.MmsConfig;
import com.android.mms.R;

import android.content.Context;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * An adapter to store icons and strings for attachment type list.
 */
public class AttachmentTypeSelectorAdapter extends IconListAdapter {
    public final static int MODE_WITH_SLIDESHOW    = 0;
    public final static int MODE_WITHOUT_SLIDESHOW = 1;

    public final static int ADD_IMAGE               = 0;
    public final static int TAKE_PICTURE            = 1;
    public final static int ADD_VIDEO               = 2;
    public final static int RECORD_VIDEO            = 3;
    public final static int ADD_SOUND               = 4;
    public final static int RECORD_SOUND            = 5;
    public final static int ADD_SLIDESHOW           = 6;

    public AttachmentTypeSelectorAdapter(Context context, int mode) {
        super(context, getData(mode, context));
    }

    public int buttonToCommand(int whichButton) {
        AttachmentListItem item = (AttachmentListItem)getItem(whichButton);
        return item.getCommand();
    }

    protected static List<IconListItem> getData(int mode, Context context) {
        List<IconListItem> data = new ArrayList<IconListItem>(7);
        addItem(data, context.getString(R.string.attach_image),
                R.drawable.ic_launcher_gallery, ADD_IMAGE);

        addItem(data, context.getString(R.string.attach_take_photo),
                R.drawable.ic_launcher_camera, TAKE_PICTURE);

        addItem(data, context.getString(R.string.attach_video),
                R.drawable.ic_launcher_video_player, ADD_VIDEO);

        addItem(data, context.getString(R.string.attach_record_video),
                R.drawable.ic_launcher_camera_record, RECORD_VIDEO);

        if (MmsConfig.getAllowAttachAudio()) {
            addItem(data, context.getString(R.string.attach_sound),
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher_musicplayer_2, ADD_SOUND);
        }

        addItem(data, context.getString(R.string.attach_record_sound),
                R.drawable.ic_launcher_record_audio, RECORD_SOUND);

        if (mode == MODE_WITH_SLIDESHOW) {
            addItem(data, context.getString(R.string.attach_slideshow),
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher_slideshow_add_sms, ADD_SLIDESHOW);
        }

        return data;
    }

    protected static void addItem(List<IconListItem> data, String title,
            int resource, int command) {
        AttachmentListItem temp = new AttachmentListItem(title, resource, command);
        data.add(temp);
    }

    public static class AttachmentListItem extends IconListAdapter.IconListItem {
        private int mCommand;

        public AttachmentListItem(String title, int resource, int command) {
            super(title, resource);

            mCommand = command;
        }

        public int getCommand() {
            return mCommand;
        }
    }
}
```

This is actually how the messaging dialog does it (the class above is from the MMS app) and you can see all the gory details by going to https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Mms/+/master/src/com/android/mms/ui and looking at the ComposeMessageActivity's `showAddAttachmentDialog` method and the `AttachmentTypeSelectorAdapter`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(); 
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for response, I have tried this, but it is not giving me the result like above(I mean only media content).

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(); 
//intent.setType("image/\*"); 
intent.setType("\*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
```

Comment: It will open image gallery only.